# Free build servers for .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, cruisecontrol.net, build-server

I've got the question... Are there any free build servers for .NET applications? We are starting project as remotely working team and right now we are searching for such solution. As far as it's an academic project we do not have funds to buy server and run CC.net on it.. Are there any charge free solutions? Or at least cheap ones...

I'm asking rather about the service on the internet, not software solution ;)

Comment: A spare PC would also do the job. You will have absolute control over the build server. It takes some time to set it up, but it is worth the effort. Alternatively find a cheap hosting solution and install CC.net on it. Maybe you can find someone who can sponsor you, because it's for an academic project or offer to put their logo on the ASP.NET page ;-).

Comment: Yeah.. In some answers they might be a little missunderstanding.. I rather asked about a server as a internet service, not as software solution.. 

@Theo Lennforff - not stupid, but I'd rather like remote service.

Comment: You mean a hosting solution for your remote service solution, which is the subject of you project? Or do you mean a service, which you can submit code to and get it build for you?

Comment: We are using assembla so we have our SVN.. right now we just need some build engine...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to check out [AppHarbor](http://appharbor.com/) - when you deploy your latest changes using git or Mercurial, your application is built automatically and any unit tests you have in the solution are run.  The application is deployed if the build and your unit tests succeed.

They also have a dashboard to view / deploy any of your 10 most recent builds.

Also:  They have a free plan.

Answer (score 9):

Another idea: do you really need your **build server** on the internet?

How about putting only your code repository on the internet (Github, Bitbucket, Google Code...)?
One of your project members could set up the build server at home. As long as it's online 24/7, it can pull the repository from the internet, make the build locally and upload the results via FTP to some webspace where you all can access it.

Of course that's not as comfortable as a "real" internet based solution, but cheap.

Answer (score 6):

[Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) is an continous integration build server. It´s written in java, but it is also compiles and builds [.NET projects](http://redsolo.blogspot.com/2008/04/guide-to-building-net-projects-using.html). As far as i know is it open source.

Answer (score 5):

Try rackspacecloud.com cloud server. They are cheap and good.

Comment: @ŁukaszW.pl: I think you will pay `hourPrice * actually time spent on build`

Comment: And while not in use, store the server image in cloud-files storage [15c per GB per month] and delete the server. Reload the server back from image and pay hourly.

Answer (score 5):

We have had good results with the following:
http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/buy/index.jsp

It is not an online solution, where you don't need an extra PC though.

Answer (score 3):

If you open source your project, you could try to get it on [teamcity.codebetter.com](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/).

This is a TeamCity enterprise edition sponsored by JetBrains, for use by open source projects.
You can read more about it [here](http://codebetter.com/blogs/james.kovacs/archive/2009/02/24/announcing-teamcity-codebetter-com.aspx), including details how to apply your project.

Answer (score -1):

For a cloud based solution, you might look into [Amazon Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/).  While technically not free, I think they offer trial and/or developer accounts for free up to a certain time period and/or bandwidth.  You might need a machine to build the code but still, you might be able to use the free account for that as well.

From the link:

> AWS Elastic Beanstalk Functionality
>
> For .NET Developers
>
> To deploy .NET applications using AWS Elastic Beanstalk, you simply:
>
> Create your application as you normally would using Microsoft Visual
>   Studio. Publish your application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk using the
>   AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio. Alternatively, you can package your
>   deployable code into a Microsoft Web Deploy .zip package and upload to
>   AWS Elastic Beanstalk using the AWS Management Console. Behind the
>   scenes, Elastic Beanstalk handles the provisioning of a load balancer
>   and the deployment of your Microsoft Web Deploy package to one or more
>   Amazon EC2 instances running Windows Server 2008 R2 and IIS 7.5.
>   Within minutes you can access your application at a customized URL
>   (e.g. http://myapp.elasticbeanstalk.com/).

Also, you can find out more about the free stuff here:

http://aws.amazon.com/free/